# Minikube with PhpStorm and Xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, minikube

I have developed a PHP based application. This application runs actually in Kubernetes and mainly using minikube on my machine. I am using PhpStorm as IDE and I also use Xdebug for debugging purposes.

What I know from my researches are that when you start PhpStorm with Xdebug, it will start listening on a port (9000 by default). When I connect to my container (in minikube), I am able to reach the IDE at the port 9000 with netcat :

```
nc <my_ip_adress> 9000
```

This shows me a message telling that connection is open so I am able to reach the IDE from my container.

Then, when I try to use Xdebug, it is not working and Xdebug doesn't stop at the breakpoint. I was guessing that IDE should also reach the container and that part I am not sure and I don't know how to do it..

Anyone already setup this kind of configuration with minikube and PhpStorm / Xdebug?

Comment: How do you start debugging in PHPStorm and Browser?

Comment: Did you follow http://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#starting and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html#start-debugging-session ?

Comment: Yes everything above was followed. The configuration was working with docker-compose. It is not working since we replaced docker-compose by minikube. For your first question, on the PhpStorm toolbar, I click on the "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" button to start listening for incoming PHP debug connections.. If that answers your question

Comment: You should provide an exact reproducible description of the steps you have done including logs and results of analytics within the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For xdebug to work, it only needs to connect to client host. there is no need for client (in this case phpstorm) to connect to your pods as well.

I have the same setup using docker for mac. What i did to make it work:

1. changed [xdebug.client_host](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#client_port) configuration to [host.docker.internal](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds) which is defined automatically in minikube /etc/host and can access host machine resources
2. made sure I have proper xdebug key defined in php.ini [xdebug.idekey](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#idekey)
3. made sure I use the [xdebug helper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) and have the same idekey defined there
4. made sure I use 9003 to listen in phpstorm which is the [default port for xdebug 3](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#client_port)

Comment: What I was missing is : "host.docker.internal". It is the way for an app running in a container to reach any service that runs on your own PC. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2):

If you try to debug a script with `xdebug_info()` in it, it will tell you exactly what Xdebug tried to do, if anything at all.

You can also make a log file by setting `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10`, and then this log file will show even greater detail as to what went on.

Please note that although a connection can be open, you might not have the *right* process. Port `9000` is also used by PHP-FPM, which is why Xdebug 3 now uses `9003` by default.